# IIS10 redirecting me from 192.168.0.1 to the start page of an old project

Tags: iis

I worked on a project with IIS and ASP.net in the past and due to COVID did it on my local machine. At the time, to test a feature that required cookies, we had to set-up the web app on the local IP address via IIS. My supervisor at the time was the one to do this. I've since left them over a year ago and have run into an issue I believe is being caused by the settings my supervisor changed at that time.

The issue is that whenever I type in my router's IP address(`192.168.0.1`, according to ipconfig), it redirects me to `https://192.168.0.1/login.asp` which was a web page we had made for the then project. My issue right now is that I can't seem to figure out or remember how to undo the changes my boss since I'm not knowledgeable about IIS nor really know where to start looking. Can anyone direct me to what I can do to fix this issue? Right now, this is mainly becoming a problem because I need to access my router to check something but I can't because of this issue.